# Dynamic content and SEO

Tags: seo, ranking, google-ranking

So, I am new on web development. I have already found a few questions from here that might help me in the future, but I would like to ask something more specific.

I have a new website with 5 pages (5 unique urls as well).

-Home page (static but minimal. Without a lot of content)
-About page (3 text paragraphs about the project and me)
-3 dynamic pages (all of them have only forms and search bar in which the user may search about the content. After they submit the form, the content are retrieved from my database and are presentened in the same page.)

Well, with my little knowledge about SEO, I can divide it in two categories. What I can do inside the website and outside of it. My question is related with the "inside" part.

What I have done until now:

- Include standard title, meta-keywords and meta-description in all of the 5 pages.
- Add Google Analytics.
- Connect it with Google Webmaster Tools.

Since, I don't have a static content, what else do you suggest me to do? Do you think that it's time to concentrate on the outside of the website, writing a few blog posts and promote it in Social Media or have I more to do inside the website?

Answer (score 1):

A few simple things that you can do

- Create a sitemap and send it to different search engines
- Write microdata that improves the metadata of your content. [Schema.org](http://schema.org/) is a good starting point.
- Ensure that your code is correct
- Provide caching system for your site ( set .htaccess )
- If you can, improve your actual content
- Ensure that your pages are as light as possible. No need to be overzealous with this, but check them.

After those steps, you can start focusing on the outside

Also, check this other helpful answers

- [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)
- [SEO: Where do I start?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22877/seo-where-do-i-start/)

[Read the Search Engine Optimization Starter Guide](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf).

Comment: 1) Do you think that a sitemap without actually content is crucial? 
2) I will search about microdata. I don't know a lot about it.
3) I don't have any errors on the console and I try to use headlines and titles whenever I can.
4) I have to check this too, since I am not familiar with it.
5) Do you mean the static content on homepage and about page? Or the dynamic one?

Comment: A sitemap is not crucial, but it always help. About improving the content, since we don't know specifics, I have to say all of it, but you are the one who has to judge. may be your content is already very useful, well written and detailed.